# Got invalid expression error , while inserting JSON data into VARIANT column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to insert **multiple** rows into a snowflake table

```
insert into sample_table  (a, b, c) values ('foo','bar',parse_json($${"def": 1}$$)),('doo','bam',parse_json($${"def": 1}$$));
```

Have tried replacing '$$' with single quotes

Getting error:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [PARSE_JSON('{"def":1}')] in VALUES clause

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use PARSE_JSON in the values section. But you can do a

```
create table sample_table(a text, b text, c variant);
```

```
insert into sample_table 
  select column1, column2, parse_json(column3) from values
    ('foo', 'bar', '{"def": 1}'),
    ('doo', 'bam', '{"def": 1}');
```

| number of rows inserted |
| --- |
| 2 |